# IIS 7.5.7600 serving 500 on php pages

Tags: php, iis-7

I'm having a problem with getting my server to serve php pages. Whenever I go to a html page, everything serves fine. However, when I attempt to go to a php page I get [page] is currently unable to handle this request. 500

The strange thing to me is that I have Word Press sites that are running perfectly fine on the same server, but when I why to view this non-wordpress php site I'm having issues.

I've tried to turned on error logging but I don't know what directory the logging is going to nor did I see where to set that, if I can.

Anyone know the reason why and how to fix?

Apache is on the machine but not being used, just in case that matters. I don't think it does though.

Thanks in advance

---

RESOLVED

I ended up deleting the site directory and the site in IIS and rebuilding it from scratch and the problem resolved itself. I don't know what triggered the issue with the php files not serving, but the php pages are serving now and the php debug is working as well. Thanks for the ideas guys.

Comment: Are you running Apache or IIS7? What have you tried?

Comment: How do you have iis and apache setup? Is wordpress being served by the apache server or iis?

Comment: We have Apache on the server but IIS7 is serving it, I only put it there so that if having it on the machine is causing issues, someone could say that. Otherwise, it's negligible

Comment: Does the IUSR user have permission to access the files in your webroot? (Check the permissions in the properties of the directory) (PS use @Terminus in your comment so that I'll get a notification that you wrote a comment)

Comment: @Terminus Did setup the user group with the correct permissinos but that didn't work.